# electron - loading page when certificate is imported

Tags: electron

I am using https and in case of a self-signed certificate, I want to prompt the user if he wants to import the required certificate. (Practically the same thing browser does when loading page without trusted certificate)

I have found out that there is a function `dialog.showCertificateTrustDialog([browserWindow, ]options, callback)` in electron which works just fine. I wanted to use it in a case when a `certificate-error`appears.

Something like this:

```
app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
    dialog.showCertificateTrustDialog({certificate:certificate, message: "some msg"}, 
        () => {
            if (was certificate ok) {
                event.preventDefault();
                callback(true);
            }
            else {
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

But I have no idea how to do the `was certificate ok` part

Is it possible? Or do I have to for example load the page again to show it? If I run the app when the certificate is already imported, it works just fine. Otherwise, I get only a blank window.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I have decided to use the following solution but it seems to me more like a hack. I try to load the page again after calling the showCertificateTrustDialog function again but if the `certificate-error` is thrown again I ignore it. I am still open to other solutions since I don't like this one

```
let certificateErrorRetry = false;

app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
  certificateErrorRetry = !certificateErrorRetry;
  if (certificateErrorRetry) {
    const {dialog} = require('electron');
    dialog.showCertificateTrustDialog({certificate: certificate, message: "some msg" }, () => {
      myapp.win.loadURL(url);
    });
  }
  else { show some error }
});
```